# Different rss feeds in a single dashboard widget

Tags: widgets, dashboard

I am using this snip of code to get rss feed on my dashboard as widget. It becomes problematic when it displays 5-6 different rss feeds which makes me run down deep.

How can I add 6 different feeds in a single dashboard widget with scroll bar?

Thanks

```
    add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'my_dashboard_widgets');
function my_dashboard_widgets() {
     global $wp_meta_boxes;
     // remove unnecessary widgets
     // var_dump( $wp_meta_boxes['dashboard'] ); // use to get all the widget IDs
     unset(
          $wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_plugins'],
          $wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core']['dashboard_secondary'],
          $wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core']['dashboard_primary']
     );
     // add a custom dashboard widget
     wp_add_dashboard_widget( 'dashboard_custom_feed', 'Latest News', 'dashboard_custom_feed_output' ); //add new RSS feed output
}
function dashboard_custom_feed_output() {
     echo '<div class="rss-widget">';
     wp_widget_rss_output(array(
          'url' => 'http://www.nytimes.com/feed',  //put your feed URL here
          'items' => 4, //how many posts to show
          'show_summary' => 1
     ));
     echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: `'url'` should work with an array of multiple URLs. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, @toscho is right, the `url` works with an array of feeds adresses. And if you have 5/6 feeds, the total of items should be 20/24.

For clear separation, I think it's better to run the `wp_widget_rss_output` function `n` number of times, and prepare a previous array with titles and addresses and iterate through it. The scroll issue is just a matter of CSS.

```
add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', 'multiple_feeds_wpse_91027' );

function multiple_feeds_wpse_91027() 
{
     wp_add_dashboard_widget( 
        'dashboard_custom_feed', 
        'Latest News', 
        'dashboard_feed_output_wpse_91027' 
    );
}

function dashboard_feed_output_wpse_91027() 
{
    // Array with Title => Address
    $feeds = array( 
        'First Feed' => 'http://example.com/feed',
        'Second Feed' => 'http://example2.com/rss', 
        'Third Feed' => 'http://example3.com/feed/',
    );
    // Set max-height and enable scrolling
    echo '<div style="max-height:300px;overflow-y:auto">';
    foreach( $feeds as $key => $value )
    {
        echo "<h3>$key</h3>";
        wp_widget_rss_output(array(
              'url' => $value,
              'items' => 4, 
              'show_summary' => 1
         ));
    }
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: +1 for the suggestion of separating the feeds - it will look much better.

Comment: Thanks Brasofilo, works like charm! I was wondering if it could fetch data asynchronously itself every hour for updation.

Comment: @10wtaylor, use the filter [**`wp_feed_cache_transient_lifetime`**](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/feed.php#L526), the default value is `12 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS`

Comment: The feeds doesn't show any visual data like any photo or video!!

Comment: That a matter for another Question, taylor ;) But confirm that the raw feed contain these elements.

Comment: yup they contain.

Comment: Ok, but that's really an issue for another Q.

Comment: Hey Brasofilo, if want to open links in new tab, how can I add target = _blank??

Answer (score 0):

You can set your widget to be of a maximum height using CSS, and then add a scroll bar to it if you wish. It's a bit of an outdated way of doing things though, and may look a bit 'naff'.

Untested, but this should do the job -

```
div.rss-widget{
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```